# How to partially update an entity and its relationships in Spring Web + JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, relationship, patch

I have these two simple entities:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;        

    //Getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="role")
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters...
}
```

In my controller i need to update a User entity using the following HTTP request

```sh
curl -X PATCH \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d \
  '{
      "username": null,
      "role": 1
  }' http://localhost:8080/users/1
```

As you can see I want that **a field can be set to null**, that **a field absent from the request should not be updated** and that **a relationship can be set using the related model ID**.

This is my attempt to achieve this in the controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRestController (UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = {RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT})
    ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId, HttpServletRequest request) {

        User userToUpdate = userRepository.findOne(userId);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User updatedUser = mapper.readerForUpdating(userToUpdate ).readValue(request.getReader());
        User user = userRepository.save(updatedUser);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

The only thing I managed to achieve is the partial update and the field to null update. This way, though, I cannot update the relationship by the ID only.
Can anybody help, please?

## UPDATE

Thanks to @Naros updated post, I rewrote the entire controller to deal with Role id updates

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = {RequestMethod.PATCH, RequestMethod.PUT})
    ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody ObjectNode requestJsonNode) throws IOException {

        User userToUpdate = userRepository.findOne(userId);

        RestMerger restMerger = new RestMerger();
        restMerger.getAssociations().put("role", userService);

        User user = (User) restMerger.merge(userToUpdate, requestJsonNode);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

I generated a *UserService* class to deal with id-entity merging functionality.

```
@Service
public class UserService implements AssociationResolver {
    public static final String ROLE_FIELD = "role";

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;    

    @Override
    public void resolveAssociation(String name, JsonNode objectNode, ObjectNode mainNode) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if(name.equals(ROLE_FIELD))
            resolveRoleAssociation(name, objectNode.get(name).asLong(), mainNode);
    }

    private void resolveRoleAssociation(String name, Long id, ObjectNode mainNode) {
        Role role = roleRepository.findOne(id);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mainNode.replace(name, mapper.convertValue(role, JsonNode.class));
    }
}
```

This service could include the full controller *updateUser* function and fields validation. The *RestMerger* class updates entities just like ObjectMapper do.

```
public class RestMerger {
    private HashMap<String, AssociationResolver> associations = new HashMap<>();

    public Object merge(Object mainObject, ObjectNode updateNode) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode mainNode = mapper.convertValue(mainObject, ObjectNode.class);

        Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();
        while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

            String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
            JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(fieldName);

            if(associations.keySet().contains(fieldName)) {
                associations.get(fieldName).resolveAssociation(fieldName, updateNode, mainNode);
            } else if (jsonNode.isObject())
                merge(jsonNode, updateNode);
            else {
                JsonNode value = updateNode.get(fieldName);
                mainNode.replace(fieldName, value);
            }
        }

        return mapper.treeToValue(mainNode, mainObject.getClass());
    }

    public HashMap<String, AssociationResolver> getAssociations() {
        return associations;
    }
}
```

And finally the *AssociationResolver* inteface makes generic *RestMerger* class interact with custom entity services

```
public interface AssociationResolver {
    void resolveAssociation(String name, JsonNode value, ObjectNode mainNode) throws JsonProcessingException;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were willing to not use `ObjectMapper`, you could recode the controller with declarative changes.  The benefit I see over `ObjectMapper` is that you control precisely what fields your RESTful interface can modify and which ones, if provided can either be silently ignored or warnings/errors issued.

*Note*: The following code snippet assumes a value object called `UserAttributes` that basically exposes valid values that the controller will accept and operate upon rather than the input being dynamic based on your original code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {

  /* other cruff */

  @RequestMapping(
    value = "/{userId}", 
    method = {
      RequestMethod.PATCH, 
      RequestMethod.PUT
  })
  public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(
    @PathVariable Long userId, 
    @RequestBody UserAttributes userAttributes) {

    User userToUpdate = userRepository.findOne(userId);
    if(userToUpdate == null) {
      /* handle cannot find user by userid */
    }

    // update the username from the user object
    userToUpdate.setUsername(userAttributes.getUserName());

    if(userAttributes.getRole() != null) {
      Role roleToUpdate = roleRepository.findOne(userAttributes.getRole());
      if(roleToUpdate == null) {
        /* handle cannot find the role */
      }
      roleToUpdate.getUsers().add(userToUpdate);
      userToUpdate.setRole(roleToUpdate);
      roleRepository.save(roleToUpdate);
    }
    else {
      userToUpdate.setRole(null);
    }

    userToUpdate = userRepository.save(userToUpdate);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(
      userToUpdate,
      new HttpHeaders(),
      HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Special `JsonNode` merge function that may help:

```
public static JsonNode merge(JsonNode mainNode, JsonNode updateNode) {

   Iterator<String> fieldNames = updateNode.fieldNames();
    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mainNode.get(fieldName);
        // if field exists and is an embedded object
        if (jsonNode != null && jsonNode.isObject()) {
            merge(jsonNode, updateNode.get(fieldName));
        }
        else {
            if (mainNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
                // Overwrite field
                JsonNode value = updateNode.get(fieldName);
                ((ObjectNode) mainNode).put(fieldName, value);
            }
        }

    }

    return mainNode;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to update a unset field if it's not sent by request, but I want to update the field just if it's set in the request even if it's set to null, so I used `ObjectMapper`. In your code snippet I seem to understand that the `UserAttribute` _role_ field is set to null both my request field is `null` (correct) and my request field is absent (incorrect). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RuggeroRusso It seems then if you want to use `ObjectMapper` you may need to perform the merge manually using `JsonNode`s. Otherwise, with my original code, you'd need to send role: [special null me value] to trigger the removal, null to skip, value to set.